# jsf jstl problem

Tags: jsf, maven, richfaces

When I try to run one of my jsf files (whom use a richfaces tag) I get the stack trace:
(when I dont use richfaces tag libs it works just fine )

```
   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config
       at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.executePageToBuildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:340)
at       com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.ja  va:150)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:96)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:135)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:309)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:306)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:541)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:383)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:243)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:288)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.Config
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
... 21 more
```

this is my web.xmal :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"   xmln    s:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
   <servlet>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
```

```
  <servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
```

```
  <context-param>
<description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
<param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
<param-value>client</param-value>
```

javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext
    resources.application

com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener

```
<context-param>
<param-name>org.ajax4jsf.VIEW_HANDLERS</param-name>
    <param-value>com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler</param-value>
</context-param>



</web-app>
```

It doesn't run on any jsp file therefore I think it got somtehing to do with not attaching the right impl to the faces config server

my project is generted by maven the problem may it be somthing wrong with the pom.xml?:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    4.0.0
    org.springframework.samples.spring
    spring-hibernate-utility
    1.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT
    jar
    Spring Hibernate Utility
    http://www.springframework.org
    
        
    
    
        true
        3.0.0.RELEASE
    
    
        
            strict
            
                false

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0.ga</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-jcl</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- added by yoav str -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-hibernate3</artifactId>
         <version>2.0.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.richfaces.framework</groupId>
        <artifactId>richfaces-impl-jsf2</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.richfaces.ui</groupId>
        <artifactId>richfaces-ui</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1.GA</version>
    </dependency><!--        

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hdiv</groupId>
        <artifactId>hdiv-jstl-taglibs-1.1.2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4</version>
    </dependency>


--></dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.springsource.bundlor</groupId>
                <artifactId>com.springsource.bundlor.maven</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.M1B</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <inherited>false</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>project</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.5</source>
                <target>1.5</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <!--forkMode>pertest</forkMode-->
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/Abstract*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
 <repository>
     <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
     </releases>
     <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
     </snapshots>
     <id>repository.jboss.com</id>
     <name>Jboss Repository for Maven</name>
     <url>
        http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/
     </url>
     <layout>default</layout>
       </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
        <id>Codehaus</id>
        <url>http://repository.codehaus.org/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<distributionManagement>
    <downloadUrl>http://www.springframework.org/download</downloadUrl>
    <site>
        <id>staging</id>
        <url>file:///${user.dir}/target/staging/org.springframework.batch.archetype/${pom.artifactId}</url>
    </site>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-release</id>
        <name>Spring Release Repository</name>
        <url>file:///${user.dir}/target/staging/release</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshot</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>file:///${user.dir}/target/staging/snapshot</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

I also get this error in the error log this might be the reason ?

```
 org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.Resource$IOWrappedException: Feature 'span' not found. (file:///C:/springsource/sts-2.5.2.RELEASE/com/sun/faces/metadata/taglib/facelets_jsf_core.taglib.xml, 453, 52)
at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLLoadImpl.handleErrors(XMLLoadImpl.java:83)
at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLLoadImpl.load(XMLLoadImpl.java:191)
at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLResourceImpl.doLoad(XMLResourceImpl.java:180)
at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceImpl.load(ResourceImpl.java:1494)
at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.facelet.core.internal.registry.taglib.TagModelLoader.loadFromInputStream(TagModelLoader.java:100)
at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.facelet.core.internal.registry.taglib.JarFileFaceletTaglibLocator.processJar(JarFileFaceletTaglibLocator.java:237)
at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.facelet.core.internal.registry.taglib.JarFileFaceletTaglibLocator.start(JarFileFaceletTaglibLocator.java:126)
at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.facelet.core.internal.registry.taglib.JarFileFaceletTaglibLocator.start(JarFileFaceletTaglibLocator.java:1)
at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.facelet.core.internal.registry.taglib.ProjectTaglibDescriptor$1.run(ProjectTaglibDescriptor.java:82)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.facelet.core.internal.registry.taglib.ProjectTaglibDescriptor.initialize(ProjectTaglibDescriptor.java:71)
at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.facelet.core.internal.registry.taglib.ProjectTaglibDescriptor.getTagLibraries(ProjectTaglibDescriptor.java:117)
at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.facelet.core.internal.registry.FaceletTagRegistry.initialize(FaceletTagRegistry.java:155)
at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.facelet.core.internal.registry.FaceletTagRegistry.getAllTagLibraries(FaceletTagRegistry.java:110)
at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.facelet.core.internal.registry.FaceletTagRegistry.getTagLibrary(FaceletTagRegistry.java:201)
at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.facelet.core.internal.metadata.FaceletNamespaceMetaDataLocator.locateMetaDataModelProviders(FaceletNamespaceMetaDataLocator.java:53)
at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.common.metadata.internal.DomainLoadingStrategy.locateMetaDataSourceInstances(DomainLoadingStrategy.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.common.metadata.internal.DomainLoadingStrategy.load(DomainLoadingStrategy.java:55)
at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.common.metadata.internal.MetaDataModel.load(MetaDataModel.java:93)
at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.common.metadata.internal.MetaDataModelManager.loadMetadata(MetaDataModelManager.java:147)
at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.common.metadata.internal.MetaDataModelManager.getModel(MetaDataModelManager.java:90)
at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.common.metadata.query.TaglibDomainMetaDataQueryHelper.getMDModel(TaglibDomainMetaDataQueryHelper.java:205)
at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.common.metadata.query.TaglibDomainMetaDataQueryHelper.getModel(TaglibDomainMetaDataQueryHelper.java:90)
at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.common.metadata.query.TaglibDomainMetaDataQueryHelper.getEntities(TaglibDomainMetaDataQueryHelper.java:123)
at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.common.metadata.query.TaglibDomainMetaDataQueryHelper.getEntity(TaglibDomainMetaDataQueryHelper.java:101)
at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.metadataprocessors.MetaDataEnabledProcessingFactory.getAttributeValueRuntimeTypeFeatureProcessors(MetaDataEnabledProcessingFactory.java:102)
at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.metadataprocessors.MetaDataEnabledProcessingFactory.getAttributeValueRuntimeTypeFeatureProcessors(MetaDataEnabledProcessingFactory.java:128)
at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.validation.internal.strategy.AttributeValidatingStrategy.validateNonELAttributeValue(AttributeValidatingStrategy.java:660)
at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.validation.internal.strategy.AttributeValidatingStrategy.access$1(AttributeValidatingStrategy.java:637)
at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.validation.internal.strategy.AttributeValidatingStrategy$1.run(AttributeValidatingStrategy.java:184)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.validation.internal.strategy.AttributeValidatingStrategy.validateAttributeValue(AttributeValidatingStrategy.java:166)
at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.validation.internal.strategy.AttributeValidatingStrategy.validate(AttributeValidatingStrategy.java:142)
at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.validation.internal.XMLViewDefnValidator.validateTag(XMLViewDefnValidator.java:99)
at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.validation.internal.XMLViewDefnValidator.validateRegions(XMLViewDefnValidator.java:177)
at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.validation.internal.XMLViewDefnValidator.validateView(XMLViewDefnValidator.java:134)
at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.ui.internal.validation.JSFValidator.validateFile(JSFValidator.java:173)
at org.eclipse.jst.jsp.core.internal.validation.JSPValidator.validate(JSPValidator.java:249)
at org.eclipse.wst.validation.Validator$V2.validate(Validator.java:1159)
at org.eclipse.wst.validation.internal.ValManager.validate(ValManager.java:704)
at org.eclipse.wst.validation.internal.ValManager$1.visit(ValManager.java:665)
at org.eclipse.wst.validation.internal.ValManager.accept(ValManager.java:810)
at org.eclipse.wst.validation.internal.ValManager.validate(ValManager.java:669)
at org.eclipse.wst.validation.internal.ValBuilderJob$Visitor.visit(ValBuilderJob.java:299)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource$2.visit(Resource.java:112)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource$1.visitElement(Resource.java:64)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTreeIterator.doIteration(ElementTreeIterator.java:82)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTreeIterator.doIteration(ElementTreeIterator.java:86)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTreeIterator.doIteration(ElementTreeIterator.java:86)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTreeIterator.iterate(ElementTreeIterator.java:127)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.accept(Resource.java:74)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.accept(Resource.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.accept(Resource.java:94)
at org.eclipse.wst.validation.internal.ValBuilderJob.fullBuild(ValBuilderJob.java:219)
at org.eclipse.wst.validation.internal.ValBuilderJob.run(ValBuilderJob.java:178)
at org.eclipse.wst.validation.internal.ValBuilderJob.runInWorkspace(ValBuilderJob.java:126)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.FeatureNotFoundException: Feature 'span' not found. (file:///C:/springsource/sts-2.5.2.RELEASE/com/sun/faces/metadata/taglib/facelets_jsf_core.taglib.xml, 453, 52)
at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.handleFeature(XMLHandler.java:1777)
at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.processElement(XMLHandler.java:1023)
at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.startElement(XMLHandler.java:1001)
at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.startElement(XMLHandler.java:712)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:501)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1363)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2755)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:395)
at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLLoadImpl.load(XMLLoadImpl.java:181)
```

thank you for the time and effort

Comment: Tomcat doesn't ship with JSTL. You need to add JSTL to your maven thing (and please fix code formatting and the English as well :) ).

Comment: NOTICE it works for everthing which is NOT richfacesw (meaning it works of the h and f prefix the problem is richfaces )

Answer (score 0):

Add this into your pom.xml:-

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: thank you for the time and effort , I have already tried it , it might be my facets..

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error in Tomcat 7.0.26 with JSF 2.1.x.  I had to roll back to JSF 2.0.x.  FYI, when adding the jstl library, I got a
[java.lang.NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7008507/jsf-page-exception/9866230)