# java.lang.NullPointerException at com.sun.faces.context.flash.ELFlash.loggingGetPhaseMapForReading

Tags: jsf-2, tomcat7, flash-scope

I am running my application in apache-tomcat-7.0.16 using JSF-2.1.2. After adding navigation rules in faces-config.xml, I am getting the NullPointerException. This bug was filed in JSF forum. Is there any compatible version between JSF and the tomcat app server or any solution for this? Error stack trace is given below:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.context.flash.ELFlash.loggingGetPhaseMapForReading(ELFlash.java:793)
    at com.sun.faces.context.flash.ELFlash.getPhaseMapForReading(ELFlash.java:826)
    at com.sun.faces.context.flash.ELFlash.isEmpty(ELFlash.java:484)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.util.DevTools.writeVariables(DevTools.java:325)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.util.DevTools.writeVariables(DevTools.java:215)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.util.DevTools.debugHtml(DevTools.java:130)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.RenderKitUtils.renderHtmlErrorPage(RenderKitUtils.java:1159)
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.throwIt(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:269)
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:141)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ExternalContextImpl.java:546)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.executePageToBuildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:364)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:154)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: Just after adding navigation rules? Show them (by the way, are you aware of implicit navigation support?). Which filed bug are you talking about?

Comment: No solution? I got the same problem with Tomcat 6.0.33.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue with Tomcat 7.0.26 and and JSF 2.1.7.  Works with JSF 2.0.9

Initially had just configured

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

But got 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config

It was only after attempting to add a dependency on jstl that I got the NullPointerException.  After rolling back to JSF 2.0.9, I also removed the dependency on jstl.

Answer (score 1):

Recently, I had a similar problem with the same error stack trace. `<welcome-file-list>` entry was like this when I got that error:

```
<welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

However, the error disappeared when I changed the entry to (denote the leading ***faces***):

```
<welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue. I was able to solve it by modifying faces-config.xml as below

```
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">


</faces-config>
```